# Get Substring from text

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I am getting urls like so from the server /myMessages/v2/messages/I7/parts/1  . I would like to retrieve the "I7"  part using javascript. The server will return similar urls which will nor have a fixed length as the numbers could be double digits . How do i retrieve whats in between the / and / after "Messages" .

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is string manipulation, not rocket science.

Comment: yes but i am new to js and would like to know the most efficient soln as whatever i m trying to do is getting ugly. I would really appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: Look at regex for javascript, for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: try regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = '/myMessages/v2/messages/I7/parts/1',
    arr = str.split('/'),
    id = arr[arr.indexOf('messages') + 1]; // 17
```

Comment: I personally like this answer more than regex because it's a little easier to turn into a general function that you can pass 'myMessages', 'messages' or 'parts', and get the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the `split` method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution:

```
var s = "/myMessages/v2/messages/I7/parts/1";
var match = /.*\/messages\/([^\/]+)/.exec(s)[1];
alert(match); // I7
```

The regex searches `s` for `"/messages/"` and then matches everything following that up to and not including the next forward slash.